# Genuine singular term vs. non genuine singular term

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, linguistics

I am reading "The Varieties of Reference" by Gareth Evans and there is that term "genuine singular term". I know what a singular term is but when is it "genuine"?

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: The word "genuine" appears to be used in a special way by Evans. I don't have the book. For context, could you quote Evan's definition of "genuine" and a typical complete sentence where "genuine singular term" appears.  Welcome to this SE!  +1

Comment: @FrankHubeny I searched the book and read very accurately, but I could not find a passage that contains a clear definition of "genuine singular term". But on page 31 Evans wrote "although I should (and shall) defend the idea that there are many kinds of singular term (paradigmatically, genuine demonstratives) [...]" I take that for now, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Gottlob Frege's [Sense and reference](http://www.scu.edu.tw/philos/98class/Peng/05.pdf) :

> It is clear from the context that by sign and name I have here understood any designation figuring as a proper name, which thus has as its meaning a definite object (this word taken in the widest range), but not a concept or a relation, which shall be discussed further in another article. The designation of a single object can also consist of several words or other signs [*see example* : "the point of intersection of a and b"]. For brevity, let every such designation be called a proper name.

In footnote, Frege refers to :

> > In the case of an actual proper name such as 'Aristotle' ...

In some texts "actual" proper names has been called "genuine" proper names. See e.g.

- Mark Textor, [Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Frege on Sense and Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=YwXHBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), page 171 :

> Frege’s footnote makes clear that this is not how things are in natural
>   language for *genuine* proper names: "In the case of an actual proper name such as ‘Aristotle’ ..."

---

See also A.N. Whitehead & B. Russell, [Principia Mathematica (1910)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA64), *Introduction*, page 64 :

> We may, in fact, distinguish names of different orders as follows: (a) Elementary names will be such as are true "proper names," i.e. conventional appellations not involving any description. (b) First-order names will be such as involve a description by means of a first-order function; [...]

---

See also : Saul Kripke, [Reference and Existence : The John Locke Lectures 1973](https://books.google.it/books?id=yWEwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13), Oxford UP (2013), page 13 :

> Russell would hold that such a name [an "empty" name] does have a sense given by a descriptive phrase. But then, he holds that the things that we ordinarily call ‘names’ aren’t really names, and that we have to leave it to analysis to discover what the *genuine* [emphasis mine] names really are. One of the criteria that are demanded by this argument to apply to names — genuine names of genuine objects — is that they have to name objects such that we can’t even meaningfully raise the question about whether they exist.

Comment: +1 thanks. That was my impression either, but I did not find any definition. Evans referred to Kripke and the introduction of a name into the language by some such 'reference-fixing' stipulation as "Let us call whoever invented the zip 'Julius'." and called this a 'descriptive name' (page 31).

For now I will interprete the "true 'proper name'" as you quoted them from Principia Mathematica. I claim these are demonstratives ultimatly. What do you think?

(Evans: "singular term (paradigmaically, genuine demonstratives)" page 31)